# Get available space on mounted device with folder with whitespaces using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I try to get Available space on mounted disk:

```
df /tmp/mount/0dfShksftN | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

It works fine but not in cases when Filesystem param has folder name with spaces.
[image]

I found solution for getting Filesystem and Mount point values in this case:

```
df -P "/mnt/MOUNT WITH SPACES/path/to/file/filename.txt" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ ]*[0-9]+%?[ ]+"}; NR==2 {print $NF}'
```

But can't find solution for Available field value. I could take the entire string and parse by myself but maybe there is a way to do this using bash,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--output` filter of `df` command.

```
df "<file-system>" --output=avail
    Avail
868215420
```

For your original approach, you may need to consider counting column backward.

From the man page of `df(1)`:

> FIELD_LIST is a comma-separated list of columns to be included.  Valid
> field names  are:  'source',  'fstype',  'itotal',  'iused',
> 'iavail',  'ipcent',
> 'size', 'used', 'avail', 'pcent', 'file' and 'target' (see info page).